# Django admin date time helpers missing

Tags: django

I have a model that includes a datetimefield...

```
# Create your models here.
class BroadcastNotification(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField()
    broadcast_on = models.DateTimeField()
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-broadcast_on']
```

In the admin pages the helpers for that field have gone away.

[image]

I don't know what I did to cause it as I didn't test everything after every change.  I did do collectstatic fairly recently if that might be the cause.

Comment: could you add your **forms.py**

Comment: Share your forms.py where you specified the help_text?